# Correct tmux disconnect

Tags: ubuntu, python, tmux

I have got ubuntu server 12.04 for android application. Application server(python, postgresql) started via tmux. 
After closing tmux terminal(or "tmux detach") on my computer, application server is still working, but some python methods fails. I can see it in database. 
When I connecting to server again(ssh and "tmux attach") - application became working correctly.
How can I correctly detach from server?

Comment: Why are you starting your app server via tmux and not the standard init system of your distribution? Also "some python methods fail" is a useless error report. Tell us exactly what's wrong.

Comment: I start it in tmux for realtime error monitoring. Sometimes I need to restart application server. I did not caught yet python exception.